# How to display error message to user when snter wrong pass

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I want when the user enters a wrong name or password to return a message to the user but does not enter into (catch) it only returns in console 401 error

````
```
[LOGIN](vuexContext, credentials) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("ip")
      axiosIns.post("login", credentials)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("lpl")
          console.log(res)
          const token = res.data.token
          localStorage.setItem('token', token)
          axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
          resolve(res)
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log("reee")
          vuexContext.commit(
            SET_ERROR,
            "incorrect password or user name")
            reject(error)
            throw error;
        });
    });
  },
``
````